# PHPMailer With Yii

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I am trying to send `email` using `PHPMailer` with `Yii` with no success. Here are my Settings:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password = "************"; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'
```

Here is my Controller Function:

```
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->From = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
            $mail->FromName = empty($_POST['EmailForm']["from_name"]) ? Yii::app()->params['emailFrom'] : $_POST['EmailForm']["from_name"];
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = nl2br($message) . $mail->Body;
            $mail->AddAddress($to);
            $mail->AddCC($cc);
            $mail->send();
```

But When I try to send an `email` the following `error` pops up:

> The following email address failed myemail@gmail.com. called mail()
>   without being connected.

Please help me solve this!

Comment: put `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` to view what's going on actually.

Comment: okay, let me try this!

Comment: it doesn't display anything :(

Comment: try this yii extension - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smtp-mail/

Comment: That message says your login has failed. Try     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'

Answer (score 0):

with smtp.gmail.com i think you should use this setting:

```
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```